# Getting Error 'Error: Unable to load PFX certificate' on a Node Js application while connecting to ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, http, elasticsearch, https

I am getting the below error stack trace while querying the elastic from NodeJs app.

```
Error: Unable to load PFX certificate
at configSecureContext (node:internal/tls:304:15)
at Object.createSecureContext (node:_tls_common:113:3)
at Object.connect (node:_tls_wrap:1619:48)
at HttpsAgent.createConnection (node:https:136:22)
at HttpsAgent.createSocket (/Users/arshpreetsingh/Desktop/Desktop – MacBook Pro/Diagnotics Services/diagnostic-search/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/_http_agent.js:265:26)
at HttpsAgent.createSocket (/Users/arshpreetsingh/Desktop/Desktop – MacBook Pro/Diagnotics Services/diagnostic-search/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/agent.js:77:11)
at HttpsAgent.addRequest (/Users/arshpreetsingh/Desktop/Desktop – MacBook Pro/Diagnotics Services/diagnostic-search/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/_http_agent.js:239:10)
at new ClientRequest (node:_http_client:305:16)
at Object.request (node:https:317:10)
at Object.request (/Users/arshpreetsingh/Desktop/Desktop – MacBook Pro/Diagnotics Services/diagnostic-search/node_modules/agent-base/patch-core.js:25:22)
```

My elastc client looks like this.

```
import elasticsearch from 'elasticsearch';
import CONFIG from '../config/index';

const elasticClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
host: CONFIG.es_url,
});


 export default {
    search: async (...args) => {
    try {
        return await elasticClient.search(...args)
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.status == 400) {
            return { hits: { total: 0 } }
        }
        throw error
    }
}
```

}

The URL of the elastic search starts with https.

Answer (score 4):

there is a way to solve this。

1. Node.js version 14.x
2. add this config
   `new elasticsearch.Client({ host: CONFIG.es_url, ssl:{ rejectUnauthorized: false } });`

Comment: In NodeJs 16 SSL verification can still be disabled with:
`new elasticsearch.Client({ host: "https://..", ssl:{ rejectUnauthorized: false, pfx: [] } });`